# Assigning Attributes In GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, attributes, glkit

I've been working with OpenGL ES 2.0 with GLKit for IOS development the last few days, and I seem to be grasping most of the concepts, but I can't seem to assign new attributes to the shaders.  I've added a new vec3 attribute to the vertex shader called NormalStuff, but when I try to run the following code it crashes on the third line.

```
    self.positionSlot = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position"))
    self.colorSlot =    GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "SourceColor"))
    self.normalSlot =   GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "NormalStuff"))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.positionSlot)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.colorSlot)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.normalSlot)
```

And here's my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;
attribute vec3 NormalStuff;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform float u_time;

void main(void) {
     DestinationColor = SourceColor;
     gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * Position;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working or how to fix it?

Also, I don't think this matters, but here's a bit more of my code:

```
  let positionSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)
  glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(Vertex)), positionSlotFirstComponent)

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorSlot)
  let colorSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(CFloat) * 3)
  glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(Vertex)), colorSlotFirstComponent)


  glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalSlot)
  let normalSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(CFloat) * 7)
  glVertexAttribPointer(normalSlot, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(Vertex)), normalSlotFirstComponent)
```